# Find 1 document be query and return the next 19 documents after that in mongodb using find() query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a dropdown select where I want to return the value currently set which is referenced by docId and then 19 other values that follow. The order of the next 19 is not important.

This needs to work with `.find()` and not aggregate,

```
[
 { docId: 'a', data: { name: 'x' }},
 { docId: 'b', data: { name: 'y' }},
 { docId: 'c', data: { name: 'z' }},
 { docId: 'd', data: { name: 't' }},
 { docId: 'e', data: { name: 'k' }},
]
```

From the following command:

`mongoCollection.find({ $or: [{docId: 'd'}, {}] }).limit(20);`

I would expect:

```
[
 { docId: 'd', data: { name: 't' }},
 { docId: 'a', data: { name: 'x' }},
 { docId: 'b', data: { name: 'y' }},
 { docId: 'c', data: { name: 'z' }},
 { docId: 'e', data: { name: 'k' }},
]
```

But what I get is just random documents, regardless of the docId passed.

Is it possible to do this with find?

I tried

```
mongoCollection.find({ $or: [{docId: 'd'}, {}] }).limit(20);
```

and

```
mongoCollection.find({ $and: [{docId: 'd'}, {}] }).limit(20);
```

and

```
mongoCollection.find({ $or: [{}, {docId: 'd'}] }).limit(20);
```

Comment: Why not with aggregate? $unionWith would be one approach

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use `aggregate` you're a little stuck.

This works as a stopgap:

```js
var targ = 'd';
doc = db.foo.findOne({docId: targ});                                           
if(doc != null) {                                                              
    c = db.foo.find({docId: {$ne:targ}}).limit(19);                             
}
```

Just for example:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {docId: targ}},
    {$unionWith: {coll: "foo", pipeline: [
        {$match: {docId: {$ne:targ}}},
        {$limit: 19}
    ]}}
]);
```